# Network error 505 http version not supported

Tags: angularjs, http, jboss

**Angularjs $http ajaxPost throwing "Network error":505 http version not supported.**

> Hello everyone, I am getting CORS after subsequent call of ajaxPost to
>   server(JBoss version 6. etc).

Please help me out.

Comment: You should provide us with a network trace of what is happening in your browser when the error occurs.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2c5ph3uasubg02k/xhr%20505%20http%20version%20not%20supported?dl=0

Comment: I have added above link which you can view ...XHR doc containing all details regarding error. I am working on angularjs v1.3.14 version, and backend web server is on JBoss 6.4. Please help me out, as it is an urgency to any feedback would always be welcome.

Comment: I have posted answer below, Please check and let me know, if some one found useful, then do comment.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid 505 http version not supported, for $http service of angular $http method POST, if using angularjs and apache server(as I am using those),

We just have to follow some basic standards,

1. Use angularjs's $http post method with set header to UTF-8 encoding like below,

```js
$http({ method: 'POST', 
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
            data: {jsonheader: {//JSON header as per requirement }, jsonbody: //JSON. Now it doesnt matter how big json you are posting },
            url: //server endpoint (http://......) }).success(function(response, status){
//handle sucess
}).error(function(error,status){
//handle error
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

2. And on the server always keep endcoding standards, like UTF-8.
3. **Note: keep in mind set CORS on server in each response. Allow CORS so that your web server will never block request from other than HTTPS;**